# Can I add buttons on to non bot's message? Telegram API

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to make a bot for "likes" feature in a telegram group. Like viber heart button. React to put  or .
How can I add these buttons on user's message. Does it work only with bot's own messages?

Comment: Please clarify the question! There are a lot of examples here how to send keyboards.

Comment: It should works like that:
- User sent a message
- Bot got the message
- Bot added buttons on the user's message

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Bots cannot modify other people's messages (unless in the context of a channel that is inapplicable here), you can re-send the message back to the user using the [copyMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#copymessage) method and attach the keyboard to that. Note that forwaded messages will not carry the reply markup with them on most cases.